# How to access call logs from J2ME apps?

Tags: java, java-me, permissions, calllog

I've been looking around and haven't found an answer to the above question. Many forums say it cannot be done in most phones, but most of those entries date back to 2006-2007 or more. I'm hoping J2ME's gotten better in the past few years. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not possible with pure j2me.

I think if you are comfortable with Symbian OS [and your targeted OS iw symbian]level coding then try J2ME JNI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just beginning to learn J2ME. are there no work around for this? Any links on what are the allowed data that can be accessed off the phone?

Comment: @Karthick can you exactly tell us your requirement so that we can have more idea for tweaks

Comment: I'm planning to use the data and draw graphs and stuff showing the user how much he talks and with whom etc.

Comment: @Karthik try at symbian level, I don't think j2me supports that

Answer (score 2):

yes.there is a way to access call logs in J2ME using J2ME API Bridge.But this interface will work on latest nokia phones.

for further details,please refer to the following link

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/J2ME_API_Bridge_Interface

Answer (score 1):

there is way now using Api bridge but it is supported for s60 3rd edition fp2 and later version
check this : http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/J2ME_API_Bridge_Interface#Logging_Service

I think its what you are looking for

Comment: which means, it won't support my mobile(s40 6th Ed). If yes, then is there any solution ..??